# Master detail uisplitViewController and UINavigationController view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I try to push from a detail view to an other view. I have a tableView in a detailView "ConRDPDetailViewController" and I will like that when I click on a row,  that push the new view "BookmarkEditorController".
here is my method in "ConRDPDetailViewController" where I try to do that :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
                ComputerBookmark* bookmark = nil;
            if([indexPath section] == SECTION_BOOKMARKS)
            {
                    // first row has either quick connect or add bookmark item
                    if([indexPath row] == 0)
                    {

                   // show add bookmark controller: is there I try to push the new View
                     BookmarkEditorController* bookmarkEditorController = [[[BookmarkEditorController alloc] initWithBookmark:[[ComputerBookmark alloc] initWithBaseDefaultParameters]] autorelease];
                     [bookmarkEditorController setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ajouter Connexion", @"Add Connection title")];
                        UINavigationController *view = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bookmarkEditorController];

                     [view.navigationController pushViewController:bookmarkEditorController animated:YES];
                     [bookmarkEditorController setDelegate:self];

                    [bookmarkEditorController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];



                     }


            }
    }
```

But nothing is happen, here is my method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder];




    // Initialize the app window
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    AuthentificationViewController *authentificationViewController =[[AuthentificationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AuthentificationView" bundle:nil];
    //self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    self.window.rootViewController = authentificationViewController;
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // The new popover look for split views was added in iOS 5.1.
    // This checks if the setting to enable it is available and
    // sets it to YES if so.
    // if ([self.splitViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setPresentsWithGesture:)])
    // [self.splitViewController setPresentsWithGesture:YES];


    return YES;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just so you know: it's 'authentication'. Don't mean to be a spelling nazi :)

Comment: @Erway Softaware This is done knowingly "Authentification" is French and not in English and I know that "Authentification" in English is "Authentication". Otherwise thank you for your comment but I doubt that it is there that comes my problem.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't know it was French.

Comment: Incase someone comes here looking for a solution in Swift and iOS8 - http://swiftwala.com/multiple-detail-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed the table view controller in a navigation controller.

Then you can push the detail view with this code:

```
BookmarkEditorController* bookmarkEditorController = [[[BookmarkEditorController alloc] initWithBookmark:[[ComputerBookmark alloc] initWithBaseDefaultParameters]] autorelease];
[bookmarkEditorController setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ajouter Connexion", @"Add Connection title")];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bookmarkEditorController animated:YES];
[bookmarkEditorController setDelegate:self];
[bookmarkEditorController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
```

Comment: thank you for you quick answer  I tried your solution before but the result is the same, no push, and more [self navigationcontroller] is null. Why??

Comment: I don't able to embed the table view controller in a navigation controller beauce the options is disable when I try via "menu choose "editor" / "embed in" / "navigation controller". It's possible to do it programmaticaly???

Comment: it is possible in the storyboard editor. try to add a navigation controller manually and connect the table view controller to it.

Comment: Please can you give me an example for adding programmaticaly a navigation controller and connect it to  tableView?? Thanks in advance